# Trying to get html texts from google url, but error 401

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am trying to retrieve some html texts from a list of google returned pages. most of them work fine, but for urls such as https://www.google.com/patents/US6034687 always gives 401 error see below

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://www.google.com/patents/US6034687
```

I am using java and I did look up on this error code, it seems authentication related, but this kind of URL can be accessed from any browsers without asking for login. So I am confused, how come only this kind of URL does not work for me.
here is my code for retrieving html

```
URL u=new URL(url);
    StringBuilder html =new StringBuilder();
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

        String out="";
        while ((out= br.readLine()) != null) {
        //   System.out.println(out);
             html.append(out+"\n");
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending a User-Agent header in the request. That **401** status is misleading. Some servers do not allow requests from non-browser clients.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0");
```

BTW, when you do openConnection() for an **https** scheme, the return value is `HttpsURLConnection`, which extends `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field. If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the prior response, and the user agent has already attempted authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication